# Is there a recommended way to recompute folds every time a buffer is changed in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, folding, foldtext, foldmethod

According to the [documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/fold.html), the only command that recompute folds is the `zx` command. However, the problem is that `zx` automatically undoes all manually opened or closed folds. If I have a bunch of folded text prior to running `zx`, all of those text would be unfolded (and the folds disappear) after I run `zx`.

My current solution is to define an autocommand to run `set foldmethod=expr` at every `InsertLeave` and `TextChange` event. However, I can't help but find this solution a bit 'hackish' and inelegant.

If anyone knows a better way, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Folds _should_ be automatically recomputed in many cases… you should only rarely if ever need commands like `zx`.